# How to configure right margin for editor in IntelliJ on per project basis

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

Is there a way to configure the Right Margin (columns) (under Code Style -> General) on a per project basis?

OR/AND is there a way to configure that same value on a per language basis. For example, I want my Java code to end at 90 columns, but my HTML to end at 120.

Thanks!

Comment: If you choose Scheme: `Project`, does that achieve per-project configuration for you?

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you! Do you know the answer to my second part of the question, i.e., making right margin different depending on what language it is (e.g., HTML vs Java)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can override the global setting with a per-language settings under Editor -> Code Style ->  -> Wrapping and Braces. Example:

[image]

Comment: A bit confusing, the settings says "Project settings" in the Preferences window, but they are only per project if you actually set the Scheme to "Project".

Comment: That is all the more annoying since the PEP 0008 for Python defines 80 characters per line but I don't know anyone giving only 80 for Java (this is normally set to 120 or even 140). Therefore a per-language-setting would definitely make sense here. Any JetBrains person reading this? :-)

Comment: I'm not familiar with python, but I agree with 120 for java, at least. Sounds like a custom plugin for intellij could do the trick? Otherwise, if you want jetbrains attention, add it on their youtrack and wait until it gets 50+ votes... ;)