# How to disable right margin only for xml in Intellij?

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I'm using Intellij 2017.3 Community Edition. I need to disable right margin only for XML and enable it for java. In Settings/Editor/Code Style, there is Hard Wrap option. If I remove this, then right margin will be disable for java also right? I don't want that to happen. I want Intellij to format java files for Right margin but not XML files. There is no option to disable Right Margin under Settings/Editor/Code Style/XML. 
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to configure right margin for editor in IntelliJ on per project basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424353/how-to-configure-right-margin-for-editor-in-intellij-on-per-project-basis)
Do you see the individual languages under code style? For me I see iot under XML->Other->Right margin

Comment: @Camilia, thanks a lot. In my version, it is named as Hard Wrap instead of right margin. There is no option to disable it. By default, it was 120 characters. I changed it to 1000 characters. It is working as required. But do you know how to disable it completely? I tried setting the value as 0, but it is not working.